# How to remove reverse rows in a permutation matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, permutation

I'm looking for a quick way in MATLAB to do the following:

Given a permutation matrix of a vector, say `[1, 2, 3]`, I would like to remove all duplicate reverse rows.

So the matrix `P = perms([1, 2, 3])`

```
3 2 1 
3 1 2     
2 3 1    
2 1 3    
1 3 2     
1 2 3
```

becomes

```
3 2 1    
3 1 2     
2 3 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can noticed that, symetrically, the first element of each rows have to be bigger than the last one:

```
n = 4;                    %row size
x = perms(1:n)            %all perms
p = x(x(:,1)>x(:,n),:)    %non symetrical perms
```

Or you can noticed that the number of rows contained by the `p` matrix follows this [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A001710) for each `n` and correspond to `size(x,1)/2` so since perms output the permutation in reverse lexicographic order:

```
n = 4;                    %row size
x = perms(1:n)            %all perms
p = x(1:size(x,1)/2,:)    %non symetrical perms
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATLAB's [`fliplr`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) method to flip your array left to right, and then use [`ismember`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find rows of `P` in the flipped version. At last, iterate all locations and select already found rows.

Here's some code (tested with Octave 5.2.0 and MATLAB Online):

```matlab
a = [1, 2, 3];
P = perms(a)

% Where can row x be found in the left right flipped version of row x?
[~, Locb] = ismember(P, fliplr(P), 'rows');

% Set up logical vector to store indices to take from P.
n = length(Locb);
idx = true(n, 1);

% Iterate all locations and set already found row to false.
for I = 1:n
  if (idx(I))
    idx(Locb(I)) = false;
  end
end

% Generate result matrix.
P_star = P(idx, :)
```

Your example:

```
P =
   3   2   1
   3   1   2
   2   3   1
   2   1   3
   1   3   2
   1   2   3

P_star =
   3   2   1
   3   1   2
   2   3   1
```

Added `4` to the example:

```
P =
   4   3   2   1
   4   3   1   2
   4   2   3   1
   4   2   1   3
   4   1   3   2
   4   1   2   3
   3   4   2   1
   3   4   1   2
   3   2   4   1
   3   2   1   4
   3   1   4   2
   3   1   2   4
   2   4   3   1
   2   4   1   3
   2   3   4   1
   2   3   1   4
   2   1   4   3
   2   1   3   4
   1   4   3   2
   1   4   2   3
   1   3   4   2
   1   3   2   4
   1   2   4   3
   1   2   3   4

P_star =
   4   3   2   1
   4   3   1   2
   4   2   3   1
   4   2   1   3
   4   1   3   2
   4   1   2   3
   3   4   2   1
   3   4   1   2
   3   2   4   1
   3   1   4   2
   2   4   3   1
   2   3   4   1
```

As demanded in your question (at least from my understanding), rows are taken from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
result = P(all(~triu(~pdist2(P,P(:,end:-1:1)))),:);
```

1. `pdist` computes the distance between rows of `P` and rows of `P(:,end:-1:1)`.
2. `~` negates the result, so that `true` corresponds to coincident pairs.
3. `triu` keeps only the upper triangular part of the matrix, so that only one of the two rows of the coincident pair will be removed.
4. `~`  negates back, so that `true` corresponds to non-coincident pairs.
5. `all` gives a row vector with `true` for rows that should be kept (because they do not coincide with any *previous* row).
6. This is used as a logical index to select rows of `P`.